# How to change part of table name dynamically in WSO2 Data Service Server query?

Tags: sql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

i need to use a parameter to complete a part of a table name in DSS query.
Example:

```
SELECT .... FROM prefix_<env>tablename;
```

where `<env>` can be a `QUERY_STRING` like parameter.

In some system (like SpagoBI) this can be done with an environment parameter like:

```
SELECT .... FROM prefix_{env}tablename;
```

and during query parameter substitution table name will be resolved to `prefix_001tablename` (in case of env=001).

In DSS i have only binding parameter syntax (`:env`) that cannot be used because there is no exact token identification (`prefix_:envtablename`).

I take a look at the code (ExpressionQuery.java) but i don't have found any way to solve this problem.

Important information: i don't have way to change table naming (i need to interact with a third party db).

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, I guess the problem is, you cannot map a named parameter called "env" to a query like "prefix_:envtablename", where only :env should be translated. So here what we can do is put "?" in the query and make it a QUERY_STRING type parameter. So ideally you should have the query like "prefix_?tablename". With that, you can pass in the parameters in the order the ? characters are mentioned in the query.

Cheers,
Anjana.